# Find cells that contain particular text

Tags: excel, vba

I have large number of text strings in an excel file and I am trying to find if any of them contain a particular text sub-string. For example column A in Sheet 1 has the text strings. Column A and B in Sheet 2 have the text sub-strings that I want to find in Sheet 1. The criteria is that both of them have to be present simulateneously. If the sub-strings from Sheet 2 are found in Sheet 1 then a particular criteria is mentioned in Column B and C in Sheet 1.

Need help with two problems in the code below. First the code I have is not working. And second how can I loop through all the sub-strings in Sheet 2 using instead of typing all of them in the code?

```
Sub Find_Text()
Dim cell As Range
Dim DataCount As Integer
With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    DataCount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & DataCount)
        If cell.Contains("sub-string_A1") And cell.Contains("sub-string_B1") Then
            Range("B" & DataCount).Value = Criteria_1 And Range("C" & DataCount).Value = Criteria_1_1
        End If
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$1000 & "*" & Sheet2!$B$1:$B$1000,A2)))),"Criteria_1","")` as an array formula confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Thanks Scott but it doesn't seem to be working. I am using a mac and when I press CMD + Return all the cells get filled with Criteria_1. Would you know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First make sure that you change the ranges to only your data set and does not include any blank cells.  Then Make sure you fill the first and hit  the cmd-Enter then copy down.

Comment: Have changed the formula to not include any blank cells. Still the same results.

Screenshot of Sheet 1 - https://www.yogile.com/gz5v3rtp/010018748l/share/?vsc=bd42bb5f

Screenshot of Sheet 2 - https://www.yogile.com/gz5v3rtp/010018746l/share/?vsc=bd42bb5f

Comment: intersting, works for me on pc.  What is the formula in B2?  Make sure the A1 Changed to A2.

Comment: Column B contains other irrelevant text. I tried this after removing column B as well but same results. The formula updates to A2 but still the same result.